# Select from wp_post and multiple meta_value from wp_postmeta

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, wpdb, sql

My lack of SQL skills has stopped me in my tracks here.

I'm trying to select post_id, post_title and two postmeta values - the first has the meta_key of 'search_country' and the second a meta_key of 'search_region'.

I think I have a working solution for retrieving just the search_country:

```
 $querystr = "
       SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID as id, $wpdb->posts.post_title as title, $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value as country
       FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
       WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
       AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'search_country' 
       AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
       AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'films'
       AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_title ASC
    ";

    $festivals = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

However, I dont know how to change this to get the search_region also?

I've never got on with SQL :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the `post_meta` table twice to the `posts` table, once for each meta value:

```
SELECT p.ID id, p.post_title title, country.meta_value country, region.meta_value region
FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} country 
    ON p.ID = country.post_id AND country.meta_key = 'search_country'
JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} region
    ON p.ID = region.post_id AND region.meta_key = 'search_region'
WHERE 
    p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p.post_type = 'films'
ORDER BY p.post_title ASC
```

I would recommend aliasing the tables (`p`, `country`, and `region`) to make it a little easier to read as you are joining the the same table twice. If you wanted another `meta_value` at the same time, you can join to the `post_meta` table additional times.

By using `JOIN` you are only returning results where the post has a value for both meta keys... if you wanted to allow one to be `NULL` you would `LEFT JOIN` the table instead.

Comment: Thanks doublesharp that is perfect! Its actually good that it only selects when there is data for both search_country and search_region as I need both anyway.  I need to read up on joins now :)